# Invalid JSON payload received with AutoML Object Detection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

When trying to run the salad example in [Object Detection AutoML quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/quickstart) I get an error. After having successfully created my dataset I run the curl command to import data:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/datasets/${DATASET}:importData -d '{
  "input_config": {
    "gcs_source": {
       "input_uris": [
         "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/openimage/csv/salads_ml_use.csv"
        ]
    }
  }
```

But I get the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected an object key or }.\n  \"input_config\": {\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I tried change the `input_config` to `inputConfig` but to no avail.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with this snippet.  Check if the gcs object is reachable.

Comment: It definitely exists (it's from an external open dataset). In the end I fixed it by just following the quickstart UI version (https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/quickstart-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not closing the payload with **'**

It should be like this one

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/datasets/${DATASET}:importData -d '{
  "input_config": {
    "gcs_source": {
       "input_uris": [
         "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/openimage/csv/salads_ml_use.csv"
        ]
    }
  }'
```